# Failed to load the JNI shared library on starting Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded the latest version of Eclipse, but I can not start it.

The error message I get is:

> Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll".

How do I fix this?

I use 64-bit Windows, 32-bit JDK, and downloaded 64-bit Eclipse.

Comment: That's strange. The jvm.dll should be in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll, not in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This usually happens if you have a 32- vs. 64-bit mismatch between the installed JDK and Eclipse versions!

Your version of Eclipse is trying to access a 32-bit JDK (as indicated by *C:\Program Files (x86)*), but either fails because Eclipse is expecting a 64-bit JDK or because the 32-bit JDK is missing - consequently you'll need to make sure to match the Eclipse and JDK versions bit wise accordingly.

Comment: I use 64 bit Windows, 32 bit JDK, and downloaded 64 bit Eclipse. Now with 32 bit Eclipse it works better, thanks.

Comment: @Jonas - I removed the erroneous assumptions about the installed versions, thanks for pointing this out by specifying your setup.

Answer (score 3):

I had installed both JDK and Eclipse 64-bit versions, but had the same issue...

Finally I discovered that my `%PATH%` system variable didn't include the folder. Don't forget to change it to the correct folder where your JDK\bin is installed. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/bin
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

use eclipse and os both 64 bit or both 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded 64-bit Eclipse and a 64-bit JDK/JRE, check the availablity of javaw.exe for 64-bit.

In my case it was in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin`

I have extracted Eclipse to the `c:\eclipse` folder; within that the `eclipse.ini` file is available. Replace the contents of that file with the following:

```
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
-framework
plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.3.R34x_v20081215-1030.jar
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xmx700m
-XX:MaxPermSize=690M
```

Leave the new line in between the -vm flag and the value. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. All I did was copy the line"

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe"

I left everything else the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had a 64 bit Eclipse and 32 bit Java and had the same issue. After installing 64 bit Java and updating ***system path***, no issues.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 you have the chance to use symbolic links as under unix.

So with `cmd` (run as an admin), run the following: `mklink /d jdk jdk-versionnr-etc` you don't need to update your path, `JAVA_JOME` the next time you update Java !

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue even though I had 64-bit versions of both JDK and Eclipse. I found out that the JDK path was missing in eclipse.ini.

So I added following lines in eclipse.ini file:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin <this might be different on your machine>
```

This solved the problem! `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

If eclipse is 64 bit , update Java in Path to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

or else

check the Java location being referred by eclipse and copy the content C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 to eclipse jre location.

Reference - http://www.buggybread.com/2013/01/failed-to-load-jni-shared-library.html

Answer (score 0):

1.Uninstall available jdk7.1 (It was 64 bit)
2. Downloaded and installed jdk7.1 32 bit.
   The jvm.dll will be in the follwing path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\bin\client"

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Steffen Opel's answer the mismatch occurs between the JVM specified in eclipse.ini file and the JVM encountered and launched as a result of the entries on your Windows path environment variable.  So to fix the issue, ensure they both refer to the same JVM.

To fix this issue follow these steps:

**1. Amend Eclipse Configuration So It Launches with Desired Version of JVM**

Open eclipse.ini and change the line below to the java version you wish to use eg:

`-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5`

**2. Ensure Eclipse Can Access the JVM It Requires**

Goto Control Panel --> Edit System Environment Variables --> Path.

    a) Make sure an entry exists here to your java

    b) Make sure this entry sits higher (or earlier) than any other java paths within your @path entry.

Hopefully that should fix the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I thought to add some more relevant info to the Accepted answer given by @Steffen Opel.

It is possible to install any number of versions of 32-bit JDKs and 64-bit JDKs in a 64-bit Windows OS. Also it is possible to install 32-bit *Eclipse* and 64-bit *Eclipse* in the same computer as well. But to run one of those platform related *Eclipse* (in OPs case 64-bit *Eclipse*) version, the machine should have matching “*Environment Variables*” configured for JDK. This can be done (should be done) without modifying 
*eclipse.ini* file.

**Environment Variables**

To run java without giving full path it is required to add file location for *java.exe* to `PATH` environment variable. And also for some other third party utilities, `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is required as well.

Normally java developers always need to have JDK installed (JRE is included in JDK). And `PATH` is set to “*bin*” folder under JDK installation folder (in OPs case *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_40\bin*) while `JAVA_HOME` is set to JDK installation folder (in OPs case *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_40*).

Here OP has only got 32-bit JDK but trying to use 64-bit Eclipse. So to fix the issue OP need to install 64-bit JDK.  And change `JAVA_HOME` & `PATH` “*Environment Variables*” to match that installation location.

***Here is the more complete steps:***

- Download and install 64-bit JDKx.x.x_xx
- Then open Windows Explorer, right click on Computer icon and select

  *Properties* -> *Advanced system settings*.
  It will open up
  *System Properties* window, and in “*Advanced*” tab select “*Environment    Variables*” to open up editing window.
- Under the *System variable* section look for `JAVA_HOME` variable
  name and click “*Edit*” button at the bottom section, if not
  available click “*New*” and enter *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_40*
  and click OK.
- Then select the `PATH` variable and click “*Edit*” and append 
  `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`; to the front or  `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the end of
  the existing string. DO NOT over write the existing string, and click
  OK -> OK ->OK to complete.

Now Eclipse will be open without the error.

**Note:**

- If someone needs to use 32-bit *Eclipse* then default JDK path will be *C:\* ***Program Files (x86)*** *\Java\jdkx.x.x_xx*
- When changing `PATH` Environment variables in Windows 10 there is an additional window will comes up as shown in picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue but I got the solution.

Check if Eclipse is 32 or 64 bits, then

1. If it is 32 bit then set JAVA_HOME to the 32 bit version of jdk
2. If Eclipse is 64 bit then set JAVA_HOME to the 64 bit version of jdk