# Running 32bit eclipse on 64bit windows

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to use a 32bit installation of eclipse on my 64bit windows machine.

I have eclipse extracted to my C: Drive and Java installed in ProgramFiles(x86)

When I go to start eclipse I get the error:Failed to load the JNI shared Library"C:Program Files(x86)\Java\jre6\bin\jvm.dll"

I looked and the file is not there.

I am setting something up wrong?Just did a fresh install of Java before trying to run eclipse.

Comment: Have you installed the 32-bit version on JDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure to have both:

- a 32bits Eclipse installation
- a 32bits Java installed: so make sure the JDK installed is actually a 32bits one, as [this comment details](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2010/07/eclipse-error-failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-cprogram-files-x86javajre6binclientjvm-dll.html#comment-826):

> I have a 64 bit Windows 7, didn't check if I had the 32 or 64 bit Java installed.
>   Easy and fast check to do, is whether or not your Java folder is in `Program Files` or `Program Files(x86)`.
>   If you've got both of these maps and it's in the x86 one, you'll need the 32 bit download.

See also the SU question "[Eclipse - Failed to load the JNI shared library](https://superuser.com/questions/186001/eclipse-failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library)"